# Node.js doesn't run HelloWorld Program in Windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I have followed many tutorials and many question on stackoverflow as well, but nothing is working from mine side.

I have make file in C: Directory name hello.js which contain
`console.log("Hello world!");`

but when i am trying to run in cmd

`node Hello.js;`

or

`node C:\Hello.js`

it throws something like that

```
 C:\Node\hello.js:1 (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ?
                                                               ^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
     at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
     at startup (node.js:139:18)
     at node.js:968:3
```

What i am missing, please explain?

Comment: Check if the file doesn't have any special characters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be some problem with your node installation.

Comment: You would have posted this as a comment

Comment: @DushyantJoshi i know i could have posted as a comment but unfortunately StackOverflow is not allowing me because i dont have reputation of 50

Answer (score 0):

`npm update` probably would have done it too. Looks like a bad version of node got published and you hit npm at just the wrong time .

Comment: How does lodash come into the picture?